# Problem in understanding a theorem

Tags: field-theory

I want to understand this :

Let $f$ be a nonconstant polynomial over the field $F$. Then there is an extension $E/F$ and
an element $\alpha  \in  E$ such that $f(\alpha ) = 0.$

Proof. I have no problem until that $F$ is identified as a subfield of $E=F[X]/I$ where $I=\langle f(x)\rangle $ and $f(x)$ is considered to be irreducible .

But then it is written that ::

**Now let $\alpha  = X+I;$ if $f(X) = a_0 +a_1 X+···+a_n X^ n $,
then $
f(α) = (a _0 + I) + a _1 (X + I) + ··· + a_n (X + I) ^n
= (a_0 + a_1 X + ··· + a_n X^ n ) + I
= f(X) + I$
which is zero in E.**

I  do not understand why $f(\alpha)=0$
because $f(X+I)=a_0+a_1(X+I)+.....+a_n(X+I)^n$ why is that zero?

I cant understand how it is so.Can anyone help here?

Comment: Which part of the statement do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly which part you don't understand, but I'll give an example that will hopefully be illuminating. This is definitely a confusing, but ingenious result.

Let's take $F=\mathbb{R}$ and consider the famous polynomial $f=x^2+1$ which we know from the order properties of $\mathbb{R}$ has no root in $\mathbb{R}$; since its degree is $2$, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore we know that $K=\mathbb{R}[t]/(f)$ is a field, since $(f)$ is a nonzero prime (hence maximal) ideal.

Let's try to get a better idea of what $K$ looks like. Any $\alpha \in K$ is the equivalence class of some polynomial $g=a_nx^n+\cdots + a_0$, and by the division algorithm we can write $g$ uniquely as $g=qf+r$ with $r=0$ or deg $r=0$ or $1$. Since $qf$ is mapped to zero in the quotient ring, we see that any $\alpha \in K$ is represented uniquely by a linear or constant polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[t]$: $\alpha=\overline{a+bx}=\overline{a}+\overline{b}\overline{x}$ (I'm using the notation $\overline{g}=g+(f)$, and since the canonical projection onto the quotient is a ring homomorphism, I can distribute the bars the way I did). As a consequence of this uniqueness, distinct real numbers are mapped to distinct elements of $K$, so we lose no information if we just write $\overline{a}+\overline{b}\overline{x}$ as $a+b\overline{x}$.

Now here's the crux. What happens when I plug $\overline{x}$ into the polynomial $x^2+1$ in $K[t]$?

I get $\overline{x}^2+1$.

What's $f+(f)$?

On the one hand it's certainly zero. On the other, $x+(f)=\overline{x}$, and $f=x^2+1$, so $\overline{f}=\overline{x^2+1}=\overline{x}^2+1$.

Thus $\overline{x}$ is a root of the polynomial $f=x^2+1$, or in other words, a square root of $-1$. With the suggestive notation $\overline{x}=i$, let's recall that any $\alpha \in K$ can be written uniquely as $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ real numbers.

What is $K$?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

The ideal $I$ in $F[X]$ is identified with $0$ of $E$. Another way to say this is, if $\pi: F[X]\rightarrow F[X]/I$ is the canonical mapping, then $I$ is the kernel. The field $F$ may be identified with the constants $a+I$ in the quotient ring so, we can view $F\subset E$ since $F$ is isomorphic to a subring of $E$.

Furthermore, if we let $\alpha = \pi (X)$, then we have $\alpha = X+I$ by the structure of the quotient ring.

If we then consider the same polynomial, but now as a polynomial in $E[Z]$ say, for indeterminant $Z$ (So $f(X)\mapsto f(Z)$ in the map $F[X]\rightarrow E[Z]$), then $\alpha$ satisfies $f(Z)$. To see this, note that $f(\alpha)=f(X+I)=f(X)+I$. By definition we have $E=F[X]/I$ and $f(X)\in I$ so, $f(X)\equiv 0$ when considered as an element of $F[X]/I$.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at $F[x]/I$ where $I = \langle f\rangle$, is to consider:

$F(u)$, where $u \in E$ is a root of $f$. This is actually isomorphic to $F[x]/I$, with the isomorphism being: $x + I \mapsto u$ (to see this actually is an isomorphism, note it's clearly surjective, and its kernel is any polynomial coset $g(x) + I$, with $g$ such that $g(u) = 0$. You can use the division algorithm to show that $f|g$).

You can then see that:

$f(x + I) = (a_0 + I) + a_1(x + I) + \cdots + a_n(x + I)^n \mapsto a_0 + a_1u + \cdots + a_nu^n = f(u) = 0$.

For example, with the irreducible polynomial $x^2 + 1$ over $\Bbb R$, the way detailed by Eoin gives: $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, in which the coset $x + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle$ is a root of $x^2 + 1$, since:

$(x + \langle x^2+1\rangle)^2 + (1 + \langle x^2+1\rangle) = (x^2 + 1) + \langle x^2+1\rangle = 0 + \langle x^2+1\rangle$, since $x^2 +1 \in \langle x^2+1\rangle$ (duh). The basic idea here is that "ideals swallow up things like zero does".

In the "alternative method", we get the field $\Bbb R(i)$, more commonly known as $\Bbb C$, the complex numbers.

The trouble with the more "natural" method, is that a priori, the *existence* of such a $u$ needs to be given. On the other hand, given the field $F$, we can certainly construct the ring $F[x]$ (in fact, this is an example of a "free structure", namely the free commutative $F$-algebra generated by the set $\{x\}$, which can be thought of as the "simplest way to make the singleton set $\{x\}$ into a commutative ring, and a vector space over $F$ in a compatible way").

Polynomial rings over a field are "nice enough" to have principal ideals (in fact, they are even Euclidean domains, which is "almost all the way to being a field"). So, given any ideal $I$, in $F[x]$, if we "factor it enough", which get something much like a prime number in the integers, an irreducible polynomial. Custom is to use a monic polynomial, which lets us write it unambiguously.

In such a "nice ring" as $F[x]$, if $I$ is generated by an irreducible, this means $I$ is a *maximal* ideal, which means $F[x]/I$ has no non-trivial proper ideals, so $F[x]/I$ is a field (it's worthwhile convincing yourself of these facts). Now, in truth, $F$ isn't "actually" a subfield of $F[x]/I$, but it turns out the maps $a \mapsto a+I$ is injective, so we can regard it as an "isomorphic copy" of $F$ inside $F[x]/I$.

The payoff to this, is: much like $\Bbb Z_p$ creates a *finite* field out of the Euclidean domain of the integers (as $\Bbb Z/(p)$), $F[x]/I$ creates a field of *finite degree* (that is, a vector space of finite dimension) over $F$. In fact, if $F$ is, itself, finite, then we get a finite field with $F[x]/I$, and *all* finite fields arise in this way.

Once having shown that $u$ actually exists, my advice is to forget it arose as a coset, and just treat it like "a number" (element of $E$). The algebra is less tiresome to look at.

Comment: I have edited the question